# pytest: mock method on Path instance to return output depending on the filename of the instance

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I am trying to mock pathlib's `is_file` method so that it returns True/False depending on my logic.

I have a function in mymodule.py to test:

```
### mymodule.py
from pathlib import Path
def myfun(root: Path):
  return root.is_file()
```

and my pytest function:

```
import mymodule

# One of my attempts
class MockPathIsFile:
    def __init__(self, existing_files):
        self.existing_files = existing_files

    def is_file(self):
        # here I am not able to get the file name (e.g. "foot.txt" or "nope.txt") to be compared with `self.existing_files`.
        if <???> in self.existing_files: 
            return True
        return False

def test_mymodule(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(mymodule.Path, "is_file", MockPathIsFile(existing_files=["foo.txt"]).is_file)
    assert mymodule.myfun(Path("foo.txt")) is True
    assert mymodule.myfun(Path("nope.txt")) is False
```

This is a stripped-down example of more complicate module I am trying to test. In the real case I am also patching `Path.glob`,`Path.open` to list and get filenames such as "foo.txt".

Comment: but then how do I pass existing_files to the function?

Comment: Please add the code that works as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def mock_is_file(existing_files):
    def mock(self: Path):
        return str(self) in existing_files
    return mock

monkeypatch.setattr(validate.Path, 'is_file', mock_is_file(existing_files=["foo"]))

assert mymodule.myfun(Path("foo.txt")) is True
assert mymodule.myfun(Path("nope.txt")) is False
```